# How to give Error message when user input wrong format of date in Java8

Tags: java, datetime-format, localdate

I want to give an error message if the user inputs using the wrong format. The correct format is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss". How can I put that as a condition?

for example 
if (yyyy <0 ) 
{ sout("please input correct year")}

this is the code i use for ask the user and formatting it

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String hour = "00:00:00";
        System.out.println("Please enter Date : ");
        String time = keyboard.next()+" "+ hour;
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(time, formatter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex comparison:

```
while input doesn't match the regex pattern
     print "Please enter date in the correct format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
continue with the rest of the code
```

The RegEx pattern could be:

> \d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d [0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d(?:.\d+)?Z?

You can use [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output) site to create and test RegEx patterns

Answer (score 0):

If the user should just enter a date (such as `2019-03-31`), there is no reason why your program should be concerned with time of day too. Furthermore, your format is ISO 8601, the format that `LocalDate` and the other the classes of java.time parse (and also print) as their default. So you don’t need an explicit formatter.

I understand that you want a range check, which is certainly advisable. In addition, if a user enters a completely different format, parsing will throw a `DateTimeParseException` which you should catch and act accordingly. For example:

```
    LocalDate minAcceptedDate = LocalDate.of(0, Month.JANUARY, 1);
    LocalDate maxAcceptedDate = LocalDate.of(4000, Month.DECEMBER, 31);

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter Date : ");
    while (true) {
        String time = keyboard.next();
        try {
            LocalDate dateTime = LocalDate.parse(time);
            if (dateTime.isBefore(minAcceptedDate) || dateTime.isAfter(maxAcceptedDate)) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a date in the range " + minAcceptedDate + " through " + maxAcceptedDate);
            } else { // OK
                break;
            }
        } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a date in format yyyy-mm-dd");
        }
    }
```

Example session:

```
Please enter Date : 
Yesterday
Please enter a date in format yyyy-mm-dd
-001-12-30
Please enter a date in format yyyy-mm-dd
5000-12-12
Please enter a date in the range 0000-01-01 through 4000-12-31
2016-09-22
```